# How to go to new line in Type Writer effect?

Tags: javascript, text, newline, effects

I have an effect of Type Writing in JavaScript for my `#effect`, I want the text to be typed in new lines where I've used `\n` in the `textEffect` variable, but the whole text is just typed consecutively, no matter I've declared `\n`s in some places,

how do I make my `textEffect` type in new lines?

```js
let x = 0;
let textEffect = "Hi, \n I'm Dorothy, \n\ have a good day!";
let container = document.getElementById("effect");

function animate() {
    if(x < textEffect.length){
        container.innerHTML += textEffect.charAt(x);
        x++;
        setTimeout(animate, 80);
    }
}
animate();
```

```html
<div id="effect"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, CSS is one way. Another way is `if (textEffect.charAt(x) === '\n')` then add `"<br>"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

style `white-space: pre-line;` needed.

```js
let x = 0;
let textEffect = "Hi, \n I'm Dorothy, \n\ have a good day!.";
let container = document.getElementById("effect");

function animate() {
    if(x < textEffect.length){
        container.innerHTML += textEffect.charAt(x);
        x++;
        setTimeout(animate, 80);
    }
}
animate();
```

```html
<div id="effect" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>
```